# Why is :lt() not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you please tell me why `:lt()` is not working. Here is my code: 
https://jsbin.com/refunuyahe/edit?html,js,output

I try to show only `100` items at first, and when the user scrolls it should show a further 100 items.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  $(function() {
    var str = '<ul id="myList">';
    var x = 100;
    var initialData = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      str += '<li>' + i + '</li>';

    }
    str += '</ul>'
    // complete data in str;
    // load only first 100 element
    $('#container').append(str);

    $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
  })

  $('#container').on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
      x += 100;
      $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
    }
  })
})();
```

Why is this line not working?

```
$('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
```

Comment: add your html and let me know

Comment: [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zyqpr9ya/)

Comment: `x` is not in scope of the last event handler. Also, your `if` statement will do nothing when hit as the `li` you're selecting will already be shown

Comment: if you will show 100 element at a time then your scroll will not shown.and then you can't add more element. anyhow at-least some elements need to be hide so that scroll comes and when you scroll.new elements will add

Comment: thanks @Tushar .but I think this is not good practice .because 1000 element are present in `DOM`

Comment: is there any way to load or come in `DOM` when user come to bottom like lazy loading

Comment: will I use any plugin for that ?

Answer (score 0):

There are main two problems with your code. Firstly the `x` variable is out of scope of the `scroll` event handler. Secondly the `li` elements are already visible on load, so calling `show()` on them would have no effect.

To fix this, place the `x` definition in a higher scope, and use CSS to only show the relevant elements when the page loads. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  'use strict';
  var x = 100;
  var str = '<ul id="myList">';
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    str += '<li>' + i + '</li>';
  }
  str += '</ul>'
  $('#container').append(str);

  $('#container').on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
      x += 100;
      $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.showItem {
  display: block;
}

/* This is the required part */
#container li:nth-child(-n+100) {
  display: list-item;
}
#container li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'></div>
```

Also note that I tidied your use of an IIFE and document.ready handlers.

Comment: thanks @rory ..!! actually here in your case `1000` item present in `DOM`.is there any way to only `100` item come in dom first time.when user scroll then load more data in DOM

Comment: That's correct - I just fixed the errors in your original logic

Comment: ok ..thanks for help .is there any way to do this.or will i use plugin

Comment: Sure, you can just use a loop to append another 100 `li` elements when the `if` condition in your scroll handler is hit

Comment: could you please share any fiddle

Answer (score -2):

I really doubt if it is correct way to achieve what you are actually trying to do. Anyway you'r missing hiding elements.

```js
(function(){
  'use strict';
  $(function(){
    var str ='<ul id="myList">';
     var x=100;
    var initialData ='';
    for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
      str+='<li>'+i+'</li>';

    }
    str +='</ul>'
     // complete data in str;
    // load only first 100 element
    $('#container').append(str);
    $('#myList li:gt('+x+')').hide(); // <-- first hide rest of li's
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
  })
  
   $('#container').on('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        x+=100;
      // HERE you need to hide elements as well
          $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
        }
    })
  
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not working. When scrolled to the end of list, next 100 elements should be shown.

Comment: It is better if OP do it himself, please find my comment in CODE. I just point him that he is not hiding the undesired LI's. Also, please avoid spoon feeding so that people can actually learn,

Comment: ok leave it ..thanks for help ..is is there any way to load or come in `DOM` when user come to bottom like lazy loading ..actually currently all data in dom.but

Comment: I don't mind, I prefer self learning by mistakes rather than getting things done by others. Anyway I suggest if you look at this plugin https://clusterize.js.org/ if you have lot of data, virtualization is really helpful.